# Center horizontally and vertically a div in a section and make each section fill the whole page when scrolling

Tags: html, css, web

I am trying to code a page where each section fills the whole page. And I am also trying to center vertically and horizontally the divs in each section.
I don't know if it's possible, if you guys can enlighten me it would be great.
I also would like to know if it's possible that, when I scroll it automatically goes to the next section. I don't know if it's clear enough to understand.

Here's the CSS :

```css
.presta .container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.presta .h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.presta card {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logoPresta:hover {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.prestaShow {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar ">
  <div class="container flex">
    <div class="logo" data-aos="fade-right">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/linko_bg_transp.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <nav data-aos="fade-in">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="pres.html">Présentation</a></li>
        <li><a href="Presta.html">Nos Prestations</a></li>
        <li><a href="form.html">Nous contacter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<section class="presta bg-light wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h1>Nos domaines d'expertises</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="grid grid-4">
      <div class="logoPresta card">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logoPresta card">
        <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logoPresta card">
        <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="logoPresta card">
        <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="prestaShow wrapper">
  <div class="container info">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2>Informatique</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="textePresta card">
      Conception & développement d'applications web
    </div>
    <div class="textePresta card">
      Création & amélioration de bases de données
    </div>
    <div class="textePresta card">
      Déploiement d'infrastructures réseaux
    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Here are the images of the page :
[image: First section]
[image: second section]

Comment: Why is this question tagged with Javascript, but does not contain such code? Also, what exactly is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: Centering multiple elements in a parent, both horizontally and vertically, is a classic usecase for a flexbox (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp ). A grid layout can work too. Automatic actions that are triggered by scroll are a matter of JavaScript, but you need to give more specific details about your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resize section to full page height by changing **100%** to **100vh**

Also, take a look at CSS section to see how to center wrappers' content (expand Code snippet to see differences).

UPD:
**.snap-wrapper** will help you to scroll full sections, take a look at Code snippet on full-screen.

```css
.presta .container {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.presta .h1 {
  font-size: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.presta card {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.logoPresta:hover {
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.prestaShow {
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  /* centering wrapper content */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

/* use .snap-wrapper to scroll page by full sections */
.snap-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100vh;
}

.snap-wrapper > .wrapper {
  scroll-snap-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="navbar ">
  <div class="container flex">
    <div class="logo" data-aos="fade-right">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="images/linko_bg_transp.png" alt="" /></a>
    </div>
    <nav data-aos="fade-in">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Accueil</a></li>
        <li><a href="pres.html">Présentation</a></li>
        <li><a href="Presta.html">Nos Prestations</a></li>
        <li><a href="form.html">Nous contacter</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="snap-wrapper">
  <section class="presta bg-light wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h1>Nos domaines d'expertises</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="grid grid-4">
        <div class="logoPresta card">
          <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="logoPresta card">
          <img src="images/2.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="logoPresta card">
          <img src="images/3.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="logoPresta card">
          <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="prestaShow wrapper">
    <div class="container info">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h2>Informatique</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="textePresta card">
        Conception & développement d'applications web
      </div>
      <div class="textePresta card">
        Création & amélioration de bases de données
      </div>
      <div class="textePresta card">
        Déploiement d'infrastructures réseaux
      </div>

    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```